# Web server replica not working in other server

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have a Drupal installation (php+mysql) in a server, and I'm trying to copy this installation to another server with the same configuration, same physical and virtual path, same db configuration, etc.

The thing is, in my new server I get the homepage to work, but not the inner pages, so I guess has something to do with rewrite (mod_rewrite is installed) (both .htaccess are the same).

When I access http://localhost/myweb/content/mypage I get a 404 or a "Forbidden" if I uncomment this in httpd.conf (original httpd.conf does not have this entry):

```
<Directory path/to/docs">
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Any clue?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have AllowOverride set to None ... .htaccess file is completely ignored by apache. It should be set to AllowOverride All.

Ref: [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

I assumed that your problem is within mod rewrite directives not properly read from .htaccess file - it might be elsewhere though ... give it a go.